# Media Creation Tool and Windows 10 Education Edition

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation

I'm currently using Windows 10 Educational Edition.

I would like to do a fresh install of this version. Although I'm worried that if I use the MCT to install windows 10 it will not accept my education key.

**Question:** Will the education key work with the MCT or would it be better just to burn the education ISO to a memory stick and go from there?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not create a recovery disk with system files and use that to re-install windows

Comment: As of November 2018, it seems the new [media creation tool for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) now accepts the education key - I used it today to do a clean reinstall on a school laptop and it accepted the previous key without issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Afaik, the tool doesn't support it. But there is a hack to get any ISO via techbench page.

- [Open this page](https://tb.rg-adguard.net/index.php?lang=en), select "Windows (final)" and your Windwos 10 Build you want to get

  [image]
- Now under `Edition`, select the Education(N) you want:[image]
- now select your Langauge

  [image]
- and your cpu architecture (32 Bit or 64Bit):

  [image]

Download the ISO from the generated link from Microsoft servers and later create a [bootable USB flash drive with Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) if needed.

Comment: You should update your link since the test bench website is dead.

Comment: @Ramhound ok, I added the new (3rd party) page that still generates the links to MS servers

Comment: Attention!!!
Generation of links to the software-download.microsoft.com service - is paused.

Comment: @Pedro77 try it again. It works for me now.