# Computer stuck in "We Couldn't Complete The Updates Undoing Changes Don't Turn Off Your Computer". How to proceed?

Tags: windows

My computer is stuck on the screen **"We Couldn't Complete The Updates Undoing Changes Don't Turn Off Your Computer."**

I have been trying solutions such as going into recovery mode, and trying to factory reset the computer, it said that it needs a image or disc version of it. Which I don't have, and I tried to do the troubleshoot on-startup, didn't work as well. Now I'm trying to factory reset it with the command prompt option they gave me, but no signs of working either it just open up the factory reset option which doesn't work for me.

Specs: Windows 8
*Only thing I know, sorry that I can't check other specs if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

boot from the Windows 8 DVD, if you need one, [use this trick to get an ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1091004/174557), or go to the Windows Recovery Environment (when you press power butto to shutdown the device for 3 times in a row), open the command prompt and run this:

```
DISM /image:C:\ /cleanup-image /revertpendingactions /ScratchDir:C:\
```

(*replace `C:` with the drive where you installed Windows 8*)

This reverts all pending operations and you should go back to Windows. Now share the folder `C:\Windows\logs\CBS` so that I can tell you what failed.

Comment: I think I'm going to try the first option you gave me, because I don't know where I installed my windows 8. One question before I download the iso file I can install windows 10 on the windows 8 computer if I want it, or no? Thank you for the response! Also if I accidently install the wrong bit will it break it even more?

Comment: after you did the undo trick and are back in Windows, you can mount the win10 ISO, run setup.exe and select upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to provide another way for a try, boot to Windows Recovery Environment as well, open the command prompt, and locate the x:\Windows\System32\config folder, (x here means the drive for your system),

Rename system to be system.old for backup, and copy x:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\system to x:\Windows\System32\config.

And then reboot your pc.

Comment: "Rename system to be system.old for backup, and copy x:\Windows\System32\config\RegBack\system to x:\Windows\System32\config. " I'm kind of confuse with this part. Is it like first rename the system file in x:\Windows\System32\config folder to be system.old then copy the \system folder to the \config folder? Also I don't know any of the command in cmd like renaming files, and moving folder/files with it. If you could provide it to me that would be great, but if not I will just try to find something. Thank you for this, I will actually try this first since I don't have a usb with me today.

Comment: Sure, here is the command: 1. cd X:\WINDOWS\system32\config (replace the X drive letter by your system drive). 2. ren system system.old  3. copy C:\WINDOWS\System32\config\regback\system C:\windows\system32\config\       For more information, please refer to: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307545, however, the c:\windows\repair in windows xp has been moved to C:\WINDOWS\System32\config\regback after Win7.